# How to display multiple images that stored as array in laravel?

Tags: laravel

please help me to display image that stored as array in database 
**my controller: 
( filename is my image column name in database)**

public function store(Request $request)
{

```
$this->validate($request, [

        'filename' => 'required',
        'filename.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'

]);

// Start multiple image upload code 
if($request->hasfile('filename'))
 {

    foreach($request->file('filename') as $image)
    {
        $name=$image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);  
        $data[] = $name;  
    }
 }
// End multiple image upload code


$houses= new House();
$houses->division = $request->input('division');
$houses->city = $request->input('city');
$houses->area = $request->input('area');
$houses->owner_name = $request->input('owner_name');
$houses->house_name = $request->input('house_name');
$houses->type = $request->input('type');
$houses->from = $request->input('from');
$houses->rent = $request->input('rent');
$houses->phone = $request->input('phone');
$houses->address = $request->input('address');
$houses->description = $request->input('description');

$houses->filename=json_encode($data); **// This for  image upload**

$houses->save();

return back()->with('success', 'Your House has been successfully');
```

}

[image column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi3Mc.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve then display the images stored as an array what I'd suggest is casting the filename attribute to json/array in the model.

You can do that in your House model like this:

```
class House extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'filename' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

To display it in a view you can loop through the casted array:

```
@foreach($house->filename as $image)
    <img src="{{ url('link/to/assets/') . $image }}"
@endforeach
```

See more in the docs about casting here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

A side point on image uploads, you may want to give uploaded files a unique name rather than using the user's filename so there's no conflict if a user uploads a document with the same name twice.

Laravel handles this all for you in the `store()` method seen here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#storing-uploaded-files. You can create your own names if preferred using `storeAs()`.

Comment: not warking, error: Property [filename] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\Users\Mobarok Hossain\Desktop\laravel\resources\views\all_house.blade.php)

Comment: Can you dd() the collection instance and update your question with the output?

Answer (score 0):

First array cast the `filename` column in your model. For more: [Array & JSON Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)

```
protected $casts = [
    'filename' => 'array',
];
```

After that, whenever you fetch filename from House model, laravel will automatically convert the json data to array. Loop through the array and display the images.

```
$house = House::find(1);
foreach($house->filename as $filename) {
    echo public_path().'/images/', $filename;
}
```

Comment: error: Property [filename] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: `filename` should be access from House model, not collection. Get a particular model, and get filename, which should be array.